# Python Tkinter return csv file directory

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, filepath

I want to write a python GUI through Tkinter to read the directory of a csv file. But I noticed that the code I have can only return the folder path instead of the file path. Is there any way I can do to track the csv file path. Here is my code

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
def browser():
    dir = askdirectory()
    if dir:
        path.set(dir)
mGui = Tk()
path = StringVar()
en = Entry(mGui, textvariable=path)
en.pack()
butt = Button(mGui, text="Browse", command=browser)
butt.pack()
mGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` or `tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()` insead.

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def browser():
    name = askopenfilename()
    if name:
        path.set(name)

....
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly I want. At the first beginning, I thought askopenfilename() will only return the name of the file, so I just ignored this function. That's a serious mistake I have made. I should try it out first. LOL, really a lesson to learn! Thank you!